DNS issue, Website only accessible through specific network service providers
I recently shifted my domain www.magina.in from Google domains to squarespace. Thinking that the transfer would be easy as google has closed it’s domain business and shared it to squarespace. After transferring suddenly my site went down. I have tried a few things but now the site is accessible through some network service providers. It’s like 50% people can see and rest get the error : magina.in’s server IP address could not be found.

A few things:
First of: I cannot see any DNS records for your domain when doing a lookup for your domain.
Like which ip address is hosting the DNS server or which ip address responds with it.
So I dug a bit further and used IN Registry's DNS tools, since they are responsible for  the .IN TLD.
According to them you have not transferred your domain to Squarespace.
See the last lines of owner information:
Name Server: ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
Name Server: ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com
Name Server: ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com
Name Server: ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com

They say that Google Domains is still responsible for any queries for your domain.
Unfortunately I cannot help in how to migrate from Google DNS to Squarespace, but the question is if you are only using Google DNS as DNS provider or are they also hosting your website / mail or other services?
If you only need them for DNS hosting, then there are plenty of other DNS providers you can use.
It is only matter of personal taste.

But a quick recap on how DNS system works:
Whenever people wants to access your website www.magina.in the will ask first ask DNS Root servers: "Who is responsible for .in TLD?"
The root servers will reply back with the ip address for IN Registrar's DNS servers.
Next we will ask IN Registar who is responsible for magina.in?
And the will at the moment get the answer back with the ip address of Google Domains DNS servers.
Next we will ask Google Domains DNS servers: "Do you have any A or AAAA record for www.magina.in ... and since Google Domains will shut down / is shutting down then there will be no answer.
This is why I say you need to update your DNS informations at IN Registry to point towards Squarespace DNS servers.

Yes we only used google domains for hosting. Our website is on wordpress. We shifted to Squarespace as google domains is shut and they recommended to shift. When we shifted to squarespace they kept our Nameservers by default  as
Name Server: ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com
Name Server: ns-cloud-d4.googledomains.com
Name Server: ns-cloud-d3.googledomains.com
Name Server: ns-cloud-d2.googledomains.com
The problem is that our website cannot be accessed via networks of certain service providers. and the error  DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN keeps coming up or servers not found keeps coming up

Well... I am using Google Public DNS to lookup your domain and even Google could not find A or AAAA for your domain. I am almost certain that you need to tell IN Registar (the owners of the Indian TLD) that your domain is now hosted by Squarespace, due to how the DNS system work.
